# Completely destroyed my gcc compiler. Need help getting it to the right state

Tags: kali-linux, gcc

To start off, I was trying to compile [this c code](https://github.com/offensive-security/exploitdb/blob/master/exploits/linux_x86-64/local/40049.c).

I was using the command the developer recommended such as

```
gcc 40049.c -m32 -O2 -o decr
```

and was getting this error

```
/usr/include/features.h:323:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
```

After doing this command

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

I thought the code could be compiled but I was wrong.

After running the same commands, I get a full text of errors in my terminal in Kali Linux machine which is shown.

```
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

This is a snippet of the errors I am receiving.

```
40049.c: In function ‘main’:
40049.c:200:19: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
  200 |  stack = (void *) malloc(65536);
      |                   ^~~~~~
40049.c:200:19: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘malloc’
40049.c: At top level:
40049.c:214:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘--’ token
  214 | --------------------------------------------------- pwn.c ---------------------------------------------------
      | ^~
40049.c: In function ‘privesc’:
40049.c:240:42: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  240 |         commit_creds(prepare_kernel_cred((uint64_t)NULL));
      |                                          ^
40049.c: At top level:
40049.c:243:5: error: redefinition of ‘main’
  243 | int main() {
      |     ^~~~
40049.c:178:5: note: previous definition of ‘main’ was here
  178 | int main(void) {
      |     ^~~~
40049.c: In function ‘main’:
40049.c:249:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memset’
  249 |  memset(shellcode, 0, 0x300000);
      |  ^~~~~~
40049.c:249:2: note: include ‘<string.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘memset’
40049.c:251:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memcpy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  251 |  void *ret = memcpy(shellcode, &privesc, 0x300);
      |              ^~~~~~
40049.c:251:14: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’
40049.c:251:14: note: include ‘<string.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘memcpy’
```

I am new to this so thank you for the help everyone.

Comment: That code is intended to be split into two different files: `decr.c` and `pwn.c`. You are saving it all as `40049.c`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but that code is intended to be split into two different files: `decr.c` and `pwn.c`. You are saving it all as `40049.c`.

See:

```
40049.c:214:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘--’ token
  214 | --------------------------------------------------- pwn.c ---------------------------------------------------
      | ^~
```

Line 214 is a marker to tell you that this is the start of the file `pwn.c`. This line isn't valid C.

Also, you have this:

```
40049.c:243:5: error: redefinition of ‘main’
  243 | int main() {
      |     ^~~~
40049.c:178:5: note: previous definition of ‘main’ was here
  178 | int main(void) {
      |     ^~~~
```

The two mains are meant to be part of two different executables.

Comment: You are right! Laziness by me, lessons learned